# Does uniform distribution belong to location and scale family?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, inference, uniform-distribution

i am doing my statistical inference class. I want to know that the uniform distribution on [a,b] belongs to location and scale family.

Comment: You have specified just one distribution, not a whole family.  How are we to make sense of your question, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any given distribution (on $\mathbb{R}$, say, or an interval) $f_0$, we can *generate* a location-scale family by 
$$
  f(x ; \mu,\sigma) =\frac1{\sigma} f(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})
$$
The distribution family most often considered with the uniform distribution is $U(0, \theta), \theta > 0$ which is a one-parameter family and so cannot be written in location-scale form.  If you with your question consider the family $U(a,b),a<b$ where $a,b$ otherwise are free, then you can write that in scale-location form. You can for example chose for $f_0$ 
$$
  f_0(x)= \frac12, \quad -1 \le x \le 1
$$

Answer (score 4):

There are many possibilities.

If you regard the basic uniform distribution as $X \sim U[0,1]$ with density $f(x)=1$ when $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise,

then for $Y \sim U[a,b]$  you could regard $a$ as the location parameter and $b-a$ as the scale parameter, i.e. $Y = a+(b-a)X$,

so $U[a,b]$ will then have density $g(y) = \frac1{b-a}f\left(\frac{y-a}{b-a}\right)$,

and this gives the density $g(y) = \frac1{b-a}$ when  $0 \le \frac{y-a}{b-a}\le 1$, i.e. when $a \le y \le b$, and $g(y)=0$ otherwise, much as you might expect

Comment: Can you comment on why $Y = a+(b-a)X$ $=>$ $g(y) = \frac1{b-a}f\left(\frac{y-a}{b-a}\right)$?

Comment: @user1916067: Three justifications would work: this is what you would expect with (a) a change in location and scale, (b) a change in variables and (c) a uniform distribution on $[a,b]$